# Getting a range of values from an Array of Months

Tags: c#, performance, algorithm, arrays

I created a array [Framework version 2.0, C# 2.0] that stores the months in a year like so

#### source

```
public readonly static string[] Months = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };
```

I am looking for a way to retrieve `IEnumerable` that returns a `range of months` from this static list. I can think of many ways but i am here to find one that makes me go wahhhhhh...
signature of the method would look something like

#### signature

`public IEnumerable<String> GetRange(int startIndex,int endIndex);`

#### sample I/O

```
startindex = 1
endindex = 10
returns months from January ,February,March upto October
```

**note:** `Array.Copy` is neat but the way parameters is used makes be go wacky

```
Parameters

sourceArray

    The Array that contains the data to copy.

sourceIndex

    A 32-bit integer that represents the index in the sourceArray at which copying begins.

destinationArray

    The Array that receives the data.

destinationIndex

    A 32-bit integer that represents the index in the destinationArray at which storing begins.

length

    A 32-bit integer that represents the number of elements to copy.
```

Comment: You could use CultureInfo.DateTimeFormat.MonthNames instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to thank every single person who put their mind to answer my question - `Thanks`
here is the code that worked for me using the Inhouse objects

#### Fetches within the range

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetRange(short startIndex, short endIndex)
    {
        /*Cases
         * end > start
         * end > bounds
         * start < bounds
         * start != end
         */
        if (startIndex > endIndex || endIndex > Months.Length || startIndex < 0 || startIndex == endIndex)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", "Invalid arguments were supplied for Start and End Index");
        }
        for (int rangeCount = startIndex-1; rangeCount < endIndex; rangeCount++)
        {
            yield return Months[rangeCount];
        }
    }
```

#### Fetches from given index upto the end

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetFrom(int startIndex)
{
    if (startIndex < 0 || startIndex > Months.Length - 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("startIndex", "Start Index cannot be greater than the Bounds of the months in year");
    }

    for (int rangeCount = startIndex - 1; rangeCount < Months.Length; rangeCount++)
    {
        yield return Months[rangeCount];
    }
}
```

> i would like to know if i could use fetch within range method inside
>   fetch from index method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Array.Copy you can do it this way:

```
public IEnumerable<String> GetRange(int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    int numToCopy = endIndex - startIndex + 1;
    string[] result = new string[numToCopy];
    Array.Copy(Months, startIndex - 1, result, 0, numToCopy); // startIndex - 1 because Array indexes are 0-based, and you want the first element to be indexed with 1
    return result;
}
```

This works with .NET 2.0

Comment: it works i do know, but another array to hold the result stop's me from doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Skip and Take Extension Methods:

```
public IEnumerable<String> GetRange(int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
    return months.Skip(startIndex).Take(endIndex - startIndex + 1);
}
```

(may need to be adjusted for 1-based indices)

Comment: they come with Linq do they? sorry i forgot to mention the framework version

Comment: Skip and Take are available since .NET 3.5

Answer (score 0):

Would something like the following work for you?

```
    public static IEnumerable<String> GetRange(int startIndex, int endIndex)
    {
        List<string> rv = new List<string>();
        for (int i=startIndex+1;i<=endIndex;i++)
            rv.Add(System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.GetMonthName(i));
        return rv;
    }
```

Comment: He's using .NET 2.0, i.e. no LINQ and no var

Comment: my sympathies to @Deeptechtons - I've revised my answer to work with 2.0